# Unable to load the requested file: helpers/common_help_helper.php

Tags: codeigniter

it cant seem to load the common helper that i created in  the helper folder 
to load the admintle for my codeigniter project.

```
enter code here


<?php 
 function public_url($url){

    return base_url('public/'.$url)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling another helper that is being used in your helper.
So you need to load the url helper in your controller before you load yours.

i.e.

```
$this->load->helper('url');         // Core URL helper for base_url()
$this->load->helper('common_help'); // This is your common_help_helper.php
```

And you have a missing ; in your function

```
function public_url($url) {
    return base_url('public/' . $url); // <<< Missing ; in your code
}
```

Comment: so should i add this to the common_help.php in the helper folder